# How to make sublists comprised of unique values from a larger list - python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, unique

I have a large list that I want to divide into smaller lists with unique values.

```
BigList = [2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3]
```

How do I divide it into smaller lists of unique values, which were originally in the bigger list (desired output below):

```
L1 = [2, 1, 0]

L2 = [2]

L3 = [2, 1]

L4 = [2, 1, 0, 3]

L5 = [0, 1, 3]
```

Note that each of the sublists don't have duplicate values, they can have a different number of indexes and all the values in all the sublists are present in the original list.

Comment: What is the criteria for a list having 3 elements, 2 elements, 1 element, etc? Also, have you attempted code for this? Can you show your code and explain what is not currently working out for you?

Comment: Do you have to maintain order?  Meaning could L1 be `[0, 2, 1]` instead?  Would that still work for your needs?

Comment: @idjaw: The next list starts when a number is come across that is already present in the list currently being worked on.

Comment: @idjaw a sublist just has to have a series of unique elements from the bigger list. I haven't attempted the code - I just started programming a few weeks ago so I'm still learning the basics. I have no idea how to approach this question and I couldn't find other related questions/answers here
sberry yeah, order is still necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple way:

```
lists = [[]]
for num in BigList:
    if num in lists[-1]:
        lists.append([])
    lists[-1].append(num)
```

It also preserves the order.  This is how it works:  it goes through each number in `BigList`.  If it is already present in the last list (`lists[-1]`), we start a new list. We then add `num` to the last list that has been created.

Comment: You could get rid of the `else:` if you just append an empty list.

Comment: @AChampion I think it would need a continue in the `if` then, otherwise it would create dupes.

Comment: Worth noting, if this `BigList` really is a **BIG LIST** then this may have poor performance.

Comment: Don't think so... `lists.append([])` would mean the following `lists[-1].append(num)` works in all cases.

Comment: @AChampion, right... if `lists.append([num])` were changed to `lists.append([])` then the else could go.  I missed the end of your comment `append an empty list`

Comment: @sberry: Good. I'll change that.

Comment: Tthanks a lot @zondo, worked like a charm!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `reduce`

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a[:-1] +[a[-1]+[b]] \
            if (b not in a[-1]) else a+[[b]],     
                 BigList[1:], 
                 [[BigList[0]]])
```

And if it were a language like Haskell, it may be possible to use. However, for Python, this may take a performance it. Nevertheless, it is a relatively simple implementation for small enough lists...